# Differences between Angular-Translate and Google Translate API?

Tags: angularjs, google-translate, angular-translate

I'm currently translating a pretty large Angular app for my company using the angular-translate module, and am mostly done with it. I'm using different json files for each language. The plan is to finish the English json file, then use a script that goes through each string of the original json file with logic, using the Google Translate API to translate and create new json files for each language.

As I'm reading over the documentation for Google Translate API, it looks as though, for a small fee, that Google Translate API can be used (with the html tags) without a real need for angular-translate since it translates dynamically.

Other than from a reliability standpoint (having translations on your own server) instead of dynamically translating (could be issues with API from time to time), what are the main differences between these 2? I haven't been able to find a comparison anywhere on here or Google. I feel like I'm going to stick with angular-translate because I need reliability and no issues, but what would be the selling point of Google. Or am I comparing apples and oranges?